# How to call WPF project in windows forms using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am creating a c# windows application and I want to call WPF project in C# windows form.

Is there any proper solution for this problem?

Comment: what to you mean by "calling project"?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to show wpf form inside winforms or call process that will start wpf app?

Comment: What is "WPF Project" and what do you mean with "call"?

Comment: i am creating one c# windows application say Form1 and i have other project in WPF say Form2, so now in Form1 by clicking button i want to call/show Form2(WPF app).

Comment: WPF is a Windows Presentation Foundation in C#, 'call' means calling other project in existing project.

Answer (score 2):

You need a WindowsForms host by using ElementHost control - see [Walkthrough: Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx)

Comment: JeffRSon, thanks for your post..